# DropDownList displaying no value despite appearing to be populated

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am reading a setting from an XML document, converting it to a string array and then looping through each string and adding them to a `DropDownList`.
Everything *appears* to be working fine, until I actually go and look at the `DropDownList` itself. No matter what I do the `DropDownList` is empty even though when I am debugging through my code everything appears to be adding itself perfectly.
If anyone could shed a little light on why nothing is displaying despite the fact from the code's point of view it is being populated, I would appreciate it.

My code can be found below (Please note I have also tried populating it via Data Binding but I am still having the same issue.):

```
public class InstrumentDropDownList : DropDownList
{
   public InstrumentDropDownList()
    {
        PopulateDropDown();
    }

    public void PopulateDropDown()
    {
        string unsplitList = Fabric.SettingsProvider.ReadSetting<string>("Setting.Location");
        string[] instrumentList = unsplitList.Split(',');

        DropDownList instrumentsDropDown = new DropDownList();

        if (instrumentList.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (string instrument in instrumentList)
            {
                instrumentsDropDown.Items.Add(instrument);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add code to your answer that shows the _usage_ of the above code?

Comment: You don't need to check whether the length of the intrumentList is greater than 0. The foreach won't let you in if the length is zero already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a new DropDownList and adding items to it.  The problem is, your not doing anything with the new DropDownList you create.  You are just adding the items to the wrong list.

```
    public void PopulateDropDown()
    {
        string unsplitList = Fabric.SettingsProvider.ReadSetting<string>("Setting.Location");
        string[] instrumentList = unsplitList.Split(',');

        if (instrumentList.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (string instrument in instrumentList)
            {
                this.Items.Add(instrument);
            }
        }
    }
```

As an alternative you should be able to do this as well.  You would obviously want to put in some more validation, but this is just to show that you can use the DataSource/DataBind

```
public void PopulateDropDown()
{
    this.DataSource = fabric.SettingsProvider.ReadSetting<string>("Setting.Location").Split(',');
    this.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you creating a new instance of the DropDownList when you are inheriting from the same class. Shouldn't you be doing something like. base.Items.Add() ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `instrumentsDropDown.DataBind` after the `foreach` statement..

Answer (score 0):

```
public class InstrumentDropDownList : DropDownList
{
   public InstrumentDropDownList()
    {
        PopulateDropDown();
    }

    public void PopulateDropDown()
    {
        string unsplitList = Fabric.SettingsProvider.ReadSetting<string>("Setting.Location");
        string[] instrumentList = unsplitList.Split(',');

        DropDownList instrumentsDropDown = new DropDownList();

        if (instrumentList.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (string instrument in instrumentList)
            {
                instrumentsDropDown.Items.Add(instrument);
            }
            instrumentsDropDown.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```